# Perl: Compare keys of 2 hashes & print the difference between the closest keys

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

**UPDATE(16/1/13)**

Borodin pointed out another possibility which I completely overlooked.
In the *actual* files (I manually sat and started looking through 46 files, each about 10MB large), there are cases where for a particular value in *File1*, no **smaller** value exists in *File2* (but a *greater* value does).

Likewise there exist cases where for a particular value in *File1*, no **greater** value exists in *File2* (but a *smaller* value does)

I am updating the sample files and the desired output here to reflect this update.

**UPDATE (15/1/13)**

I have updated the desired output to account for a case where a value in *File1*  **matches** a value in *File2*. Thanks to Borodin for pointing out such a scenario.

---

I have 2 files which look like the following :

**File1**

```
 chr1   10227  
 chr1   447989  
 chr1   535362
 chr1   856788
chr1    249240496
```

**File2**

```
chr1    11017
chr1    11068
chr1    23525
chr1    439583
chr1    454089
chr1    460017
chr1    544711
chr1    546239
chr1    856788
chr1    249213429
chr1    249214499
chr1    249239072
```

What I need to do is that foreach value in *file1*, eg. `10227`, find from *file2* ,  **two** values which are closest. One of these values would be bigger, and the other smaller.
So taking `10227` in *file1*, the values which are closest in *file2* are `9250` and `11017`. Now the difference needs to be computed viz `9250 - 10227` = `-977` and `11017 - 10227` = `790` to give an output like the following (tab delimited) :

**Desired Output**

```
chr1   10227   No   790   No Match
chr1   447989  No   6100  -8406
chr1   535362  No   9349  -75345
chr1   856788  Yes  
chr1   249240496 No No Match -25997
```

I figured the fastest way to do this would be to use a hash to read in the 2 files, taking the numbers as `keys` and assigning `1` as value.

The code I have written so far is giving the difference of `10227` wrt all the values in *file2*. Similarly with `447989` and `535682`.
How do I stop this and find the difference of only the closest numbers, one which is >`10227` and one which is <`10227`

**Code**

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

#code to enter lsdpeak and pg4 data into hash with KEYS as the numerical values, VALUE as 1

#Assign filename
my $file1 = 'lsdpeakmid.txt';
my $file2 = 'pg4mid.txt';

#Open file
open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die $!;

#Read in file linewise
my %hash1;
while(<$fh1>){

    my $key1 = (split)[1];
    $hash1{$key1} = 1;

}


    my %hash2;
    while(<$fh2>){
        my $key2 = (split)[1];

    }


foreach my $key1 (sort keys %hash1){

    foreach my $key2 (sort keys %hash2){

    say $key2-$key1;

    }

}

#Exit
exit;
```

Thank you for taking the time to go through the problem. I would be grateful for any and every comment/answer.

Comment: Are the numbers in both files sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @melpomene Yes they are. They are not continuous, but are definitely in ascending order

Comment: What if there is a value in `file2` that *matches* one in `file1`?

Comment: @Borodin Well, it is unlikely, but yes there is a possibility. In such a case, a **0** should be printed indicating that the values match.

Comment: @Borodin I have updated the desired output to account for such a possibility. For the sake of future parsing (possible) of output file, I figured a simple `Yes` for a match would be better.

Comment: I have only a tablet with me and can't easily write a revised solution without a PC. I will try to remember to come back to this question when I get home at the end of the week. You still have to consider what to do if all boundaries are less than or greater than any one value - i.e. there is no interval that contains the value.

Comment: @Borodin How can I ever thank you for pointing these things out. I completely overlooked the 2nd scenario. I have updated the question accordingly. The question is still open for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

open my $fh1,'<','file1' or die $!;
open my $fh2,'<','file2' or die $!;
my %h1;

while(<$fh2>){
        chomp;
        my ($k,$v)=split(/\s+/);
        push @{$h1{$k}}, $v;
}
close $fh2;

while (<$fh1>){
        chomp;
        my ($k, $v)=split(/\s+/);
        my $bef=first{$_ >= $v}@{$h1{$k}};
        $bef=defined $bef?$bef-$v:"No match";
        my $aft=first{$_ <= $v}reverse @{$h1{$k}};
        $aft=defined $aft?$aft-$v:"No match";
        my $str=sprintf("%-8s %-10d %-5s %-8s %-8s",$k, $v,$bef?"No":"Yes",$bef?$bef:"",$aft?$aft:"");
        print $str, "\n";
}
close $fh1;
```

The first `while` loop reads the second file and creates a hash where the key is chr1 and the value is an array reference containing all the values of chr1.

The `foreach` block sorts all the keys in numerical order.
  The 2nd `while` loop processes the records of file1 and uses the `first` function of `List::Util` to get the results.

The `first` function is used twice: Once, to get the first biggest value than the current value, second: to get the last smallest value than the current value which is obtained by using the `first` on a `reverse` `sort`ed array.

**First function**:
First function returns the first number in the array which satisfies the condition.

`first{$_ > $v}@{$h1{$k}}` => This gets the first number in the array which is bigger than the current number. Say for 10227, first will return 11017.

The next thing needed is the last smallest number before 10227. To get this, the first function is applied on the reverse array.

`first{$_ < $v}reverse @{$h1{$k}}` => This will return the first number which is lesser than 10227, and since the array is reversed, what we get is actually the last smallest number before 10227 which is 9250.

On running this:

```
chr1     10227      No    790      No match
chr1     447989     No    6100     -8406
chr1     535362     No    9349     -75345
chr1     856788     Yes
chr1     249240496  No    No match -1424
```

Comment: Hello Guru! Thanks for your answer. I just need a little more clarification. Could you please explain step by step, how the _second_ `first` function is being used here : `(first{$_ < $v}reverse @{$h1{$k}})-$v`

Comment: Many thanks for the clarifications. The idea of `reverse` is fantastic! Do you think this code could be updated a bit to include any chance occurrence where $_ = $v? For eg. would this work : `if (first{$_ eq $v}@{$h1{$k}}) {say "0" }` ?

Comment: You mean you are referring to a situation if a number being equal in the 2nd file? If so, can you please post the expected result in your original post in case of matching numbers?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am updating the expected result in such a situation.

Comment: Borodin has pointed out another possibility which I completely overlooked. I have updated the question in that regard. I'd be grateful if you could have a look at the update I've posted today.

Comment: Hello thanks for the update. Could you please explain what these 2 lines of code do : **1.** `$bef=defined $bef?$bef-$v:"No match";` ,**2.** `sprintf("%-8s %-10d %-5s %-8s %-8s",$k, $v,$bef?"No":"Yes",$bef?$bef:"",$aft?$aft:"");`  These are novel syntaxes for me.

Comment: 1. If $bef does not contain anything, assign "No match" else substract it by $v.   2. sprintf line is used to format the print statement

Comment: So `?` in `$bef=defined $bef?$bef-$v:"No match";` means "does not contain" right? I looked up the `perldoc` for `sprintf` but could not find any similar example for the syntax. I am guessing `%-8s` prints 8 spaces? So what would `%-10d` be doing?

Comment: For the `?` , see the section conditional operator in [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)   and `%-8s` means align it to the left of width 8.

Answer (score 2):

A hash is not a good choice here, as the only way to find the correct boundaries from `file2` is to search through the list of values, and a hash doesn't facilitate that.

This program works by putting all the boundaries from `file2` into the array `@boundaries`, and then searching through this array for each value read from `file1` to find the first boundary value that is greater. Then this and the previous boundaries are the ones required, and the arithmetic is done in the `print` statement.

Note that this code will have problems if `file2` contains a *matching* boundary, or if there is no boundary greater than or none less than a given value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $file1 = 'lsdpeakmid.txt';
my $file2 = 'pg4mid.txt';

my @boundaries = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $file2 or die $!;
  map { (split)[1] } <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @vals = split ' ', $line;
  my $val = $vals[-1];
  for my $i (1 .. $#boundaries) {
    if ($boundaries[$i] > $val) {
      print join(' ', @vals, $boundaries[$i] - $val, $boundaries[$i-1] - $val), "\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
chr1 10227 790 -977
chr1 447989 6100 -8406
chr1 535362 9349 -75345
```

Comment: Hello again sir! I request some additional clarifications.  **1** Why is it necessary to use both `map` & `split` to put the elements in `@boundaries`. Wouldn't a simple `split` work?

Comment: **2.** What does `LINE` do?

Comment: **3.** How is it ensured in this line of code `$boundaries[$i] - $val, $boundaries[$i-1] - $val` that the first greatest boundary element & first lowest boundary element are taken?

Comment: `LINE` is a label that allows me to write `next LINE` within the inner `for` loop. Without it, `next` would start the next iteration of the `for` instead of going to read the next line of the file. And because you can guarantee that `file2` is sorted, if I search from the beginning for the first value that is greater than `$val` then clearly the previous value is less than `$val`. As I noted in the answer, this works only if none of the boundaries match the value and there is always at least one lesser boundary and one greater.

Comment: I have refactored my code to avoid the need for a label, as it should have been written in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First, we read in the second file and put the values into an *array*. I further assume that this `chr1` is constant and can be discarded safely:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my @file2;
open my $fh2, "<", "file2" or die $!;
while (<$fh2>) {
  my (undef, $num) = split;
  die "the number contains illegal characters" if $num =~ /\D/;
  push @file2, $num;
}
@file2 = sort {$a <=> $b} @file2; # sort ascending
# remove previous line if sorting is already guaranteed.
```

Then, we define a sub to find the two values in our array. It is just a variation of a basic algorithm to find a certain value in a sorted list (in *O(log n)*), and should perform better than iterating over each value, at least on large sets. Also, it doesn't require reversing the whole list for each value.

```
sub find {
  my ($num, $arrayref) = @_;

  # exit if array is too small
  return unless @$arrayref >= 2;
  # exit if $num is outside the values of this array (-1 is last element)
  return if $num <= $arrayref->[0] or $arrayref->[-1] < $num;

   my ($lo, $hi) = (1, $#$arrayref);
  my $i = int(($lo+$hi)/2); # start in the middle

  # iterate until
  #   a) the previous index contains a number that is smaller than $num and
  #   b) the current index contains a number that is greater or equal to $num.
  until($arrayref->[$i-1] < $num and $num <= $arrayref->[$i]) {
    # make $i the next lower or upper bound.
    # instead of going into an infinite loop (which would happen if we
    # assign $i to a variable that already holds the same value), we discard
    # the value and move on towards the middle.
          # $i is too small
    if    ($num >  $arrayref->[$i]  ) { $lo = ($lo == $i ? $i+1 : $i) }
          # $i is too large
    elsif ($num <= $arrayref->[$i-1]) { $hi = ($hi == $i ? $i-1 : $i) }
          # in case I made an error:
    else                              { die "illegal state" }
    # calculate the next index
    $i  = int(($lo+$hi)/2);
  }
  return @{$arrayref}[$i-1, $i];
}
```

The rest is trivial:

```
open my $fh1, "<", "file1" or die $!;
while (<$fh1>) {
  my ($chr, $num) = split;
  die "the number contains illegal characters" if $num =~ /\D/;
  if (my ($lo, $hi) = find($num, \@file2)) {
    if ($hi == $num) {
      print join("\t", $chr, $num, "Yes"), "\n";
    } else {
      print join("\t", $chr, $num, "No", $hi-$num, $lo-$num), "\n";
    }
  } else {
    # no matching numbers were found in file 2
    print join("\t", $chr, $num, "No-match"), "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
chr1    10227   No      790     -977                                                            
chr1    447989  No      6100    -8406                                                           
chr1    535362  No      9349    -75345                                                          
chr1    856788  Yes
```

Comment: Hello again sir! Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate the subroutine step by step? I have been trying to understand it since last night(hence the lack of comments till now) and while I was able to figure out what `->` means and even make it work with the alternate `$$` and can also see the implementation is a `binary search` algorithm, the exact sequence of flow is eluding me..

Comment: @Neal I improved the algorithm; it now coveres more cases and won't go into an infinite loop any longer. Also, I added some comments that should make it easier to understand. `->[$index]` ist just used to dereference values from the array reference. The output code now distinguishes between a found match and a missed match.

Comment: **Example:** Array from `0` to `8`. We want to find `5`. **Init:** `$lo=1`, `$hi=8` and `$i=int(4.5)=4`. **First iteration:** The value at `$i-1` is `3`, and the value at `$i` is `4`. `$i` is too small, so now `$lo=4`. New `$i` is `6`. **Next iteration:** The value at `$i-1` is `5` and the value at `$i` is `6`. `$i` is too large, so now `$hi=6`. New `$i` is `5`. **Next iteration:** The value at `$i-1` is `4` and the value at `$i` is `5`. The termination condition matches. The two values are returned.

Comment: Many thanks. I am going through it again. Meanwhile, Borodin pointed out another possibility which I had completely overlooked. I have updated the question accordingly.